# Temporary profile error when creating Reporting Service Application

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

This is the first time I am setting up a farm, so please bear with me. The SharePoint farm has following servers:

- 2 SP Web Front Ends(Having Load balancing)
- 2 SP Application Servers
- 1 SP Database Server(Clustered)
  We needed to install and configure reporting service and we performed following:
- Installed SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode and SSRS SharePoint add-ins in both the Application servers, Installation went fine without any error.
- Installed SSRS SharePoint add-ins in both the Web Front End servers, Installation went fine without any error.
- When we checked whether the service is running in all 4 or not, it was running fine in both the application servers but was only running on 1 SP Web Front End Servers. When we tried running it on the other server it failed with an error saying we need to stop the service in the other Web Front End server and then try again. All in all, we were not able to run the service on both the Web Front End Servers. **This is one of the issues we are not able to resolve.**
- Then we thought of creating Reporting Services Service Application and Application Pool on the Web Front End server which has the service running on it. **When we tried creating the service we got the below error**

[image]

Will really appreciate any guidance

Comment: Dear Mohit, could you share the ULS Log files releated to the Correlation ID you are receiving?